# How to tell if `geth` connected to EVM One?

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm using the EVM One back-end with `ewasm/geth` according to the following [instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/evmone#usage).

Geth seems to be starting up as usual with the following command:

```
geth --vm.evm=./libevmone.dylib
```

How can I actually tell if the library has been linked successfully and the new back-end is being used?

FYI - performance seems relatively similar, so my suspicion is that it's not being applied.